# Java Future: get the time per request

Tags: java, time, future, latency

I have a piece of code that needs to make 15 requests in parallel then wait for all the requests to complete before proceeding.

Each request takes somewhere between 500-2500 ms. Is there a way in Java to get the time it takes for each future to complete the request?

Comment: If you want to wait for all the threads to complete and then proceed, you can use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any built in methods in the Future api itself. However, if you use [ListenableFutures](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained), you can start a timer when you make the future and and stop the timer in the onSuccess or onFailure callback. Concretely, this could look something like:

```
public void timeRequests(MyRequests[] requestsToMake) {
  ListeningExecutorService service =  MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(requestsToMake.length));
long startTimeNanos = System.nanoTime();
long[] endTimes= new long[requestsToMake.length]
for(int i =0; i < requestsToMake.length; i++){
    MyRequest req = requestsToMake[i];
    ListenableFuture<MyData> rFuture = service.submit(new  Callable<MyRequest>() {
  public MyData call() {
 return req.makeRequest();
 }
});
Futures.addCallback(rFuture, new FutureCallback<MyData>() {

 public void onSuccess(MyData data) {
    endTimes[i]=System.nanoTime();
   //whatever else you do
}
public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
    endTimes[i]=System.nanoTime();
   //whatever else you do
}
});
}
```